# How to intentionally corrupt an ext4 filesystem?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, ext4, filesystem-corruption

I want to intentionally corrupt a file on an ext4 filesystem for testing.  Is there a way to corrupt it by, say, leaving a file open and then rebooting?

Comment: Open file, pull power plug?

Comment: open a file just with vim?

Comment: I'd rather make numerous changes to a DB and then plug out the power when the only commit to all transactions is started.

Comment: As asked, how corrupt do you want the file? You could always open the file in question in a hex editor and remove the first couple of bytes and the last couple of bytes .. or in the hex editor, just randomly go through and make random changes to hex .. no power pulling or `dd` needed ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you want to be able to recover? Or how corrupt are we talking?

I would use `dd`, a block transfer utility.

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sdWV count=X bs=Y seek=Z
```

where

**sdWV** is the device you wish to corrupt

- **sdW** will be the block device
- **V** will be the partition number

**X** is the number of bocks you want to write

**Y** is the size of each block

**Z** is the place on the partition where you want to start corrupting data

Make sure you make a backup before you do any corruption.

Here, the image source will be `/dev/urandom`, a stream that will just generate random data, overwriting anything and everything on your device.

If you omit the `count` directive, it will continue writing until the device is full up.

**edit**

Heh, sorry about the corruption to your current running system - your post title and body differ very much. Corrupting a *filesystem* and corrupting a *file* are pretty different...

If you want to corrupt the file, you can still use dd, but output overwriting an existing file - not the actual block device.

```
~ > echo "this is a test file that is about to be corrupted" > test_file
~ > cat test_file
this is a test file that is about to be corrupted
~ > dd if=/dev/urandom of=test_file bs=8 count=1 seek=1
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
8 bytes (8 B) copied, 0.007185 s, 1.1 kB/s
~ > cat test_file
this is \o♣▒▒▒_C~ >
```

Comment: Should it not be /dev/sdWV where W is the device and V is the partition number?

Comment: `offset` should be `seek` no?

Comment: i just blew away what i think was `/sbin/init`.  is there a more controlled corruption that might just corrupt a file that lives in my home directory and force the filesystem to remount as read-only?

Comment: ahhh... sorry, I misread - your post title and post body differ - so you want to corrupt just a file, not the filesystem? See my edit.

Comment: Can I ask, what exactly are you trying to test? This might help to better find a more adequate method of corruption.